# How to put a text right-sided in centered an equation?

Tags: empheq

My MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{backcolor}{RGB}{255,255,170}
\newcommand*\mybox[1]{%
\colorbox{backcolor}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align}
V=I \cdot R
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

and displaying

[image]

But, that I want the equation in center (without changing place) and its text in nearly right. See below the image,

[image]

Is there a solution?

Related to: [How to align text to the right in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131263/how-to-align-text-to-the-right-in-math-mode)

and

[Text to the right of piecewise equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129710/text-to-the-right-of-piecewise-equation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{backcolor}{RGB}{255,255,170}
\newcommand*\mybox[1]{%
\colorbox{backcolor}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align}
V &=I \cdot R \rlap{\qquad\text{Some text}}\\
P &= V \cdot I \rlap{\qquad\text{Some text here again}}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\text` is not actually needed but never hurts to use.

Comment: `\text` was needed if you used `\mathrlap`...

Comment: Perfect working, [CLOSED].

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, that is what I meant. May be I should have used `here` :-)